# Change Text Size through preferences

Tags: java, android, listadapter

I was wondering if anyone could help me with a question.

How would I change the text size of a textView depending on preferences?
within my preferences I have a radiogroup and would like the text size to change based on which radio button is checked.
I have came up with the following but this does not work.

```
SharedPreferences getData = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String values = getData.getString("list", "4");

    if (values.contentEquals("1")){
        tv1.setTextSize(20);
    }
```

The following is for the menu I want to change:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this, R.layout.mylist, classes));
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you didn't declare the list parameter right in your `SharedPreferences`.

My bet is that `getString` return 4 because "list" doesn't has a value.

so what heppens if you change to:

```
 if (values.contentEquals("4")){
        tv1.setTextSize(20);
    }
```

Comment: When I do this again nothing happens to the text.  Also when I change the preferences with the change size code and I change preferences If I close the app on my phone and re open it, the app crashes.